# UINavigationController clips subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using a navigation controller that's slightly offset from the edges of the screen. When I try to animate subviews out of the navigation controller frame, they get clipped. I tried setting:

```
navigationController.view.clipsToBounds = NO;
navigationController.view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

but to no avail.

I've attached an illustration:

[image: Illustration]

Comment: Can you share screenshot?

Comment: self.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO; simply add this line

Comment: can you attach your screenshot?

Comment: Instead of making your navigation controller smaller, try making your subviews the smaller size.

Comment: so you want views to stick out from the navigation controller? If that's the case you can either move the views to another view (although they look like they're part of your navigation controller's view) or walk over navigation controller's view hierarchy setting `clipsToBounds = NO` on each view. Or, just create a tabbed UI like Apple does :)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I also have situation where navigation controller clips subviews, nothing works.

Comment: The issue is with the navigation controller's view's subview, `UINavigationTransitionView`.

Answer (score 3):

Solved.
as you see in view hierarchy for UINavigationController:
[image: view hierarchy for UINavigationController]

the UINavigationController has a subview named UILayoutContainerView.
then UILayoutContainerView has a subview named UINavigationTransitionView. this view is the problem. you must turn of clipsToBounds for it. (the default for this view is on).
then UINavigationTransitionView has a subview named UIViewControllerWrapperView.
clipsToBounds for UILayoutContainerView and UIViewControllerWrapperView is off by default. but clipsToBounds for UINavigationTransitionView is on by default.
you must turn it off in code:

```
self.navVc.view.subviews[0].clipsToBounds = false
```

Answer (score 2):

I had almost the same problem, but navigation bar content was going off it's frames. Try this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

To fix issues with views inside try to change a viewController's clipsToBounds property:

```
for (UIViewController *vc in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    vc.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

I'm not sure, it will work.

Comment: By the way, clipsToBounds is NO by default. Probably, I would do something else, rather than playing with this property. Sorry. I don't know what to do then. I need more code around and screenshot. How are you animating your subviews?